# 'array.each do |block|' including results of statement in generated Haml HTML

Tags: ruby, haml

I am generating an email with dynamic content from a Haml template which parses info from an array.

Basically, the Haml receives an array filled with several hashes. In the code I have a block which looks like this:

```
%table 
  =arrayname.each do |object|
    %tr
      %td= object.name
      %td= object.link
```

Whenever the email is sent the entire object `arrayname` is included at the *bottom* of the HTML. This causes `[#,#]` (more # when there are more objects) to show up at the *top* of the block. There is no way to manipulate this piece of text with CSS, else I would've just hidden it.

```
[#<Release @id=181 @title="test" @amurl="test.com" @iturl="test.com" @cover="test.com" @date="2012-03-28" @artist_name="Test">, #<Release @id=182 @title="test" @amurl="test.com" @iturl="test.com" @cover="" @date="2012-03-31" @artist_name="Test">]
```

The line is identical to the results shown when executing the code in IRB.

Can anyone tell me how to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With Haml, you don't need to use an `=` for `arrayname.each` because that's Ruby code you want run, but not displayed. To just *run* code, use a hyphen.

Instead, this should work:

```
%table 
  - arrayname.each do |object|
    %tr
      %td= object.name
      %td= object.link
```

Comment: Pork me sideways. I should have either read the Haml reference better or posted on here earlier. The silly things I have tried... Thanks a lot!